# Use count where id=id - oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

using oracle live sql trying to display a "Standings" view,
two tables in use would be MATCH and TEAM
so every time MATCH.WIN_TEAM = the id of a team it shows as a count

I guess I'm having issues with my count function. I know i can easily pull up where

so it would be 
TEAM_NAME    WINS

This is pulling up just the teams,subquery isn't working. am i on the right track?

```
select A.TEAM, B.W
from TEAM A
       left join 
       (
       select MATCH.WIN_TEAM, 
                     Count(MATCH.WIN_TEAM) as W
       from   MATCH

       group by MATCH.WIN_TEAM
       ) B
on A.ID = B.WIN_TEAM
order by B.W desc;
```

im a newb, halp. I'm guessing i need aliases too?

Comment: Why do you use an alias equal to the name of the table? It ´s better if you use a diferent one

Answer (score 0):

```
select TEAM.NAME ,copy_match.count_match
from TEAM 
    left join (select MATCH.WIN_TEAM as WIN_TEAM, 
                      Count(MATCH.WIN_TEAM) AS count_match
               from   MATCH
               group by MATCH.WIN_TEAM
               ) copy_match
    on TEAM.ID=copy_match.WIN_TEAM;
```

Comment: genius. so we just used a different alias, and referred to that alias duh.. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Even if, technically, it works, I think you are over complicating your query

```
select TEAM.NAME ,COUNT(MATCH.WIN_TEAM)
from TEAM 
left join
MATCH ON TEAM.ID=MATCH.WIN_TEAM
GROUP BY TEAM.NAME
ORDER BY COUNT(MATCH.WIN_TEAM)
```

Isn't this version a little easier ?  Or maybe i missed a detail